# Cucumber reporting hide Before and After hooks

Tags: maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

in version 2.0.0 of maven-cucumber-reporting plugin is it possible to hide `@Before` and `@After` hooks from the report?

so for example in the html report I see:

```
Before BusinessStepDefs.prepare()
Scenario: Business scenario
  Given business specific input
  When performing action
  Then result is success
  After HelperStepDefs.cleanUp()
```

I am using the version 2.0.0, using an older version did not have those lines. Any ideas ?

I would  like this to appear as

```
Scenario: Business scenario
  Given business specific input
  When performing action
  Then result is success
```

Comment: There is a [2.1.0](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22net.masterthought%22%20AND%20a%3A%22cucumber-reporting%22) version. I searched the [code repository](https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting) for "Before" and didn't spot anything.

Comment: Scratch that. The 2.1.0 link was to 'net.masterthought : cucumber-reporting : 2.1.0' not maven-cucumber-reporting.

Answer (score 0):

See this [issue](https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting/issues/282) for a discussion and possible resolution.